# where can I buy bus tickets in Podgorica?

Tags: public-transport, montenegro, podgorica

According to http://podgorica.me/saobracaj/ , there is public transport in Podgorica - there is a dozen lines of local buses. Where can I buy tickets for those buses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A driver sells tickets. A ticket costs 90 eurocents.